# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to make a dataset with image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: image, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I get UnicodeDecodeError, when trying to load my own dataset. My directory has structure:

```
main_dir 
--train
----class1
----class2
--val
--test
```

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.utils.image_dataset import image_dataset_from_directory

in_folder = 118
size = 256
data_dir = r"C:\programming\Python\Programs\fonts_render\AI_train"

train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir + r"\train",
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=2,
    image_size=(size, size),
    batch_size=in_folder
)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir + r"\val",
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode='categorical',
    seed=2,
    image_size=(size, size),
    batch_size=in_folder)
```

I was experimenting with arguments, but I always get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programming\Python\Programs\fonts_render\AI.py", line 12, in <module>
    train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\image_dataset.py", line 210, in image_dataset_from_directory
    image_paths, labels, class_names = dataset_utils.index_directory(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\dataset_utils.py", line 573, in index_directory
    partial_filenames, partial_labels = res.get()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\dataset_utils.py", line 644, in index_subdirectory
    for root, fname in valid_files:
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\dataset_utils.py", line 619, in iter_valid_files
    for root, _, files in sorted(walk, key=lambda x: x[0]):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 876, in walk_v2
    if is_directory(full_path):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 689, in is_directory
    return is_directory_v2(dirname)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 703, in is_directory_v2
    return _pywrap_file_io.IsDirectory(compat.path_to_bytes(path))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 76: invalid start byte
```

I work with images, what can't it read? Are there problems with structure?

I also tried:

```
main_dir
...class1
...class2
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the same code works on Linux. I don`t know why, but I think that's because of coding issues on Windows.